# How To Use do_shortcode with WooCommerce One Page Checkout

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I'm trying to use the WordPress `do_shortcode` function for the WooCommerce One Page Checkout Plugin which uses shortcode like this: `[woocommerce_one_page_checkout template="product-table" product_ids="product, ids, here"]`. I can ONLY use this shortcode IF it's in the content editor and it won't allow me to add this to a page template using the `do_shortcode` function.

Their documentation [here](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/#can-i-display-the-one-page-checkout-shortcode-using-the-do-shortcode-function) says:

> If you wish to display the One Page Checkout Shortcode using
> WordPress’ do_shortcode() function instead of including the shortcode
> in a post or page’s content, you will also need to attach custom code
> to the 'is_wcopc_checkout' filter and make sure a boolean true value
> is returned.

So I tried adding the following to the functions.php file:

`add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', '__return_true' );`

I also tried

`add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', function(){ return true; } );`

and it didn't work either.

I also tried:

```
add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', 'my_one_page_checkout' );
function my_one_page_checkout(){
  return true;
}
add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', 'true' );
```

That didn't seem to do it either.

Am I adding this code to the functions.php wrong? I don't seem to see that there is a filter named `is_wcopc_checkout` in the code of WooCommerce one page checkout version 1.0.2

**Any help on how I can get the One Page Checkout Plugin to work using `do_shortcode`?**

Here's my full code in the page template for reference:

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_one_page_checkout template="product-table" product_ids="62, 122, 438, 52, 433, 435, 512, 514"]');
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

(I tried contacting WooCommerce support and they were no help saying that this is custom code and they can't do anything to help.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution that has worked for me so far:

If you use the full `do_shortcode()` as in your example, and you also put the basic `[woocommerce_one_page_checkout]` shortcode (even without any attributes) into the content field, that seems to be enough to load the missing scripts and load the checkout form.

Not ideal but better than nothing because at least you can still programatically build out the `do_shortcode()` function in PHP to do whatever you need.

This probably works because of what is stated in [this part](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/#can-i-display-the-one-page-checkout-shortcode-using-the-do-shortcode-function) of the documentation:

> To display a working checkout form, One Page Checkout needs to enqueue a variety of scripts and styles prior to outputting the content on the page. In order to do this, **it will check if the current post content to determine if it contains the One Page Checkout shortcode**, and only add the require styles and scripts when it does (to avoid loading them on all pages)

Comment: I tried this out and didn't seem to work.